# plotly scatter chart plotting x

Tags: angular, angularjs, plotly, scatter-plot, web-worker

I am attempting to create a scatter chart using Plotly, where I need to display 60 traces, each with around 1000 data points. The data arrives approximately every 100ms. I have implemented a web worker to process the data, **but I'm still experiencing lag on the screen**. I've tried to optimize my code using promises.
And used batch processing
But after sometime the batch array is also getting full due to data speed
I have used 2 web worker for the processing.
**Main Thread Code:**
In the main thread code, the plotSpectrogramChart function initializes the chart, and updateSpectrogramChart is responsible for updating it. Data is processed through a queue system to alleviate the lag. The main thread communicates with web workers to offload processing.
**Web Worker Code:**
The web worker handles data processing using the updateSpectrogramChart function, which generates traces for the scatter plot based on the incoming data. Colors are determined by the getColorBasedOnRange function. The worker communicates back to the main thread with the results.

````
// Main thread code
function plotSpectrogramChart(frequency, amplitude) {
  const spectrogramChart = document.getElementById('spectrogramChart');
  Plotly.newPlot(spectrogramChart, [], getLayout());
  updateSpectrogramChart(frequency, amplitude);
}

function getLayout() {
  return {
    title: 'Scatter Plot with Colored Data Points',
    xaxis: { title: 'Freq. (MHz)' },
    yaxis: { showticklabels: false },
    showlegend: false,
  };
}

async function updateSpectrogramChart(frequency, amplitude) {
  console.time();
  const worker = workers[workerIndex];
  workerIndex = (workerIndex + 1) % numWorkers;
  
  dataQueue.push({ worker, frequency, amplitude, maxY: maxY++, minY: minY++, traceCount: traceCount++ });

  if (!processingData) {
    processQueue(2);
  }
}

async function processQueue(batchSize) {
  if (dataQueue.length > 0) {
    processingData = true;
    const batch = dataQueue.splice(0, batchSize);
    console.log('dataQueue', dataQueue.length);
    console.log('batchSize', batch.length);

    const batchResults = await Promise.all(
      batch.map(({ worker, frequency, amplitude, maxY, minY, traceCount }) =>
        postMessageToWorker(worker, frequency, amplitude, maxY, minY, traceCount)
      )
    );

    for (const result of batchResults) {
      if (result) {
        handleWorkerResult(result);
      }
    }

    processingData = false;
    processQueue(batchSize);
  }
}

function postMessageToWorker(worker, frequency, amplitude, maxY, minY, traceCount) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    worker.postMessage({
      action: 'updateSpectrogramChart',
      frequency,
      amplitude,
      maxY,
    });

    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      let data = {
        traces: event.data,
        maxY,
        minY,
        traceCount,
      };
      resolve(data);
    };
  });
}

function handleWorkerResult(result) {
  if (spectrogramChart.data.length > 49) {
    Plotly.deleteTraces(spectrogramChart, 0);
    traceCount--;
  }

  Plotly.addTraces(spectrogramChart, result.traces);
  Plotly.relayout(spectrogramChart, { 'yaxis.range': [result.minY, result.maxY] });
  console.timeEnd();
}

// Web worker code
addEventListener('message', ({ data }) => {
  if (data.action === 'updateSpectrogramChart') {
    const { frequency, amplitude, maxY } = data;
    postMessage(updateSpectrogramChart(frequency, amplitude, maxY));
  }
});

function updateSpectrogramChart(frequency, amplitude, maxY) {
  const colors = amplitude.map(getColorBasedOnRange);
  const traces = [
    {
      x: frequency,
      y: Array(frequency.length).fill(maxY),
      mode: 'markers',
      type: 'scattergl',
      marker: {
        color: colors,
        size: 8,
        symbol: 'square',
      },
    },
  ];
  return traces;
}

function getColorBasedOnRange(num) {
  if (num === null || num === undefined) {
    return 'grey';
  }

  if (num < -45) return 'indigo';
  if (num < -35) return 'blue';
  if (num < -25) return 'green';
  if (num < -15) return 'yellow';
  if (num < -5) return 'orange';
  if (num <= Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) return 'red';
  return 'grey';
}```
i want to reduce the lag for that i have tried multiple approach like web workers and promises to render the chart
````